# Rails, rspec and rake db:test:prepare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've just added a column to one of my tables, and when I run Rspec I get the error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: ...
```

The Cucumber feature that covers the scenario where this additional attribute is used runs without error.

When I run:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

I receive the deprecation warning that's been around for a while, however, if I now run Rspec again, the unit test runs fine, and the newly added attribute is found fine by the DB query.

I'm just wondering if there is something I'm missing in my Rspec config because I'm sure I shouldn't have to run db:test:prepare for Rspec to use the updated Schema.

Many thanks

Paul

Comment: How did you add the column? If you created a migration, why didn't Rspec warned you that you should run `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate` and failed?

Comment: Hi EugZol, I just used a normal migration, and got no warnings

Comment: I wasn't aware I had to do anything after rake db:migrate because the deprecation warning states: The Rails test helper now maintains your test schema automatically.

Comment: That's strange. Well, anyway, adding `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` to the top of your `spec_helper` should do what you need.

Comment: `rails_helper` does, but your `spec_helper` probably didn't :)

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I'll try a dummy migration and test tomorrow. I don't seem to be able to mark your answer as correct (if it works tomorrow), so sorry about that, I would if I could. :)